# How to fix the variables collection object throwing "object required (424)" error?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save the value of a variable for future use.
For this I referred to Microsoft's VBA reference.
The page taught me that I could save the value of the variable in the Document's Variable object.
However, even on pasting the exact code from the [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends) into my VBA, it will throw error

> RunTime Error 424 Object Required

The exact code I am trying to execute is

```
Sub AddDocumentVariable() 
    ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="Age", Value:=12 
End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your question please to include the exact code you're trying to execute.

Comment: The code makes sense in **Word**, not so much in **Excel**

Comment: I have edited to include the code @Gareth

Comment: @VarunKhanna The documentation you're referring to is Word documentation. Are you trying to set a new workbook name in the name manager?

Comment: @Gareth I need a quick way to keep the value of a variable in memory  after I have closed the workbook.

Comment: @VarunKhanna Save it in a hidden sheet?

Comment: You need to reply your question, mentioning the code is related to Word and not Excel and then close it.